# Adding text using buttons with javascript and altering it using another button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set the cases as solved or not solved using the button "Uløst" for not solved and "løst" for solved.

Atm I am able to change the color from white to red if not solved and white to green if solved. Now I want to add "løst" or "Ikke løst" inside the

```
 <li id="status" class="Case-info">Status:(here)</li>
```

based on the button I click.

If I press "Uløst" the status should display like this "Status: ikke løst"
If I press "Løst" the status should display like this "Status: løst"

Here is a link to Codepen for the current [issue][1]

```
    function solved(){
        document.getElementById("weapon").style.borderColor ="green";
    };

    function notSolved(){
         document.getElementById("weapon").style.borderColor ="red";
    };
    body{
        
        height: 100%;
        background-image:  url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490822061517-61b5e64bf21c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
            
    }

    h2{
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
    }

    img{
        background: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .gallery{
    text-align: center;
      height: 400px;
      width: 600px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }



    #logo{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        padding
    }

    .top-nav {
      background-color: black;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .topnavlinks {
      float: right;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
        
    }

    .top-nav a:hover {
      background-color: slategray;
      color: black;
    }

    .top-nav a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    #main-content-grid{
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 1rem;
    }

    #index-button{
        margin: 0.5rem;
        width: 25%;
        height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #555555;
        border: solid, 15px, black;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: white;
        outline: none;   
        display: inline;
    }

    .img-fluid{
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .Case-info{
        color: black;
        background: white;    
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size-adjust: auto;
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    /*
        Mobile code        
    */

    .col-xs-12{
        grid-column: auto / span 12;
    }       

    /*
        Media queries
        *******
    */        

    /*
        Tablet
    */
    @media (min-width: 760px){

        .col-md-12{
            grid-column: auto / span 12;
        }

        .col-md-6{
            grid-column: auto / span 6;
        }            
    }

    /*        
        Smallest desktop >992px
    */        
    @media (min-width: 992px){
        .col-lg-12{
            grid-column: auto / span 12;
        }
        .col-lg-6{
            grid-column: auto / span 6;
        }
        .col-lg-4{
            grid-column: auto / span 4;
        }
    }


    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1rem;
        border: 2px, grey;
    }

    li{
        
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    input{
        width: 50%;
        height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #555555;
        border: solid, 15px, black;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: white;
        outline: none;    
    }


    #spacing{
        height: 8rem;
    }

    #weapon{
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    .top-nav{
        background: white;
    }
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Våpen smuglere</title>
        <script src="/Script/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Script/weapons.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/weaponsmugler.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
       
       <div class="top-nav">
      <a href="Index.html">
          <img id=logo src="bilder/PST.png" alt="PST logo">
      </a>
      <a class="topnavlinks" href="login.html">Logg ut</a>
      <a  class="topnavlinks"href="Admin.html">Ny sak</a>
    </div>
       
       
       <div id="container">
        
        <div id="spacing">
            
        </div>
                
                        
           <main id="main-content-grid">
               
               <article id="weapon" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li id="status" class="Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input class="solved" onclick="notSolved()" type="button" value="Uløst">
                   <input class="solved" onclick="solved()" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
 <article id="weapon" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li id="status" class="Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input class="solved" onclick="notSolved()" type="button" value="Uløst">
                   <input class="solved" onclick="solved()" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
 <article id="weapon" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li id="status" class="Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input class="solved" onclick="notSolved()" type="button" value="Uløst">
                   <input class="solved" onclick="solved()" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
               
           </main>
           
       </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question. You saw the big, red warning about posting links to other sites without code in your question, yet you actively ignored it and tried to sidestep that rule.

Comment: Is this better? I did not understand the red warning, should I not include a link to the codepen?

Comment: There's no need for codepen when SO has runnable stack snippets available in the question. Look for the `<>` button. And yes, that's better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use document.getElementById paired with .innerHTML to set the text value upon clicking the button.  What this will do is select that list item with the ID of status, then it'll reset the text value inside that HTML element.  Let me know if that makes sense and let me know if this helps.

```
function solved(){
    document.getElementById("weapon").style.borderColor ="green";
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status: løst";
};

function notSolved(){
     document.getElementById("weapon").style.borderColor ="red";
     document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status: ikke løst";
};
```

EDIT: Updated code below to take into account multiple sections (see comments below).

So, first of all as mentioned in my comments in HTML you can't use the same ID for multiple HTML elements, IDs inherently must be unique (e.g. shouldn't be using multiple "weapon" or "status" IDs).  I updated the code to make your CSS for the weapon ID for a new weapon class, then added that to those relevant HTML elements.  You can add multiple classes to an HTML element by adding a space between each class name.

Then I added unique IDs to each weapon, status and button.  Then, one thing you can do with onClick event handlers is you can pass in this.id, which gives your function access to the id of the HTML element that called the function.  Then, in the function itself I used basic if/else conditional logic to check what id was being called to apply the necessary formatting.

HTML

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Våpen smuglere</title>
        <script src="/Script/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Script/weapons.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/weaponsmugler.css">

    </head>
    <body>

       <div class="top-nav">
      <a href="Index.html">
          <img id=logo src="bilder/PST.png" alt="PST logo">
      </a>
      <a class="topnavlinks" href="login.html">Logg ut</a>
      <a  class="topnavlinks"href="Admin.html">Ny sak</a>
    </div>


       <div id="container">

        <div id="spacing">

        </div>


           <main id="main-content-grid">

               <article id="weapon1" class="weapon col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li id="status1" class="Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input id="button__not-solved1" class="solved" onclick="notSolved(this.id)" type="button" value="Uløst">
                    <input id="button__solved1" class="solved" onclick="solved(this.id)" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
 <article id="weapon2" class="weapon col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li id="status2" class="Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input id="button__not-solved2" class="solved" onclick="notSolved(this.id)" type="button" value="Uløst">
                    <input id="button__solved2" class="solved" onclick="solved(this.id)" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
 <article id="weapon3" class="weapon col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li id="status3" class="Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input id="button__not-solved3" class="solved" onclick="notSolved(this.id)" type="button" value="Uløst">
                    <input id="button__solved3" class="solved" onclick="solved(this.id)" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>

           </main>

       </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS (just change #weapon to .weapon)

```
.weapon{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function solved(id){  
  if (id === "button__solved1") {
    document.getElementById("weapon1").style.borderColor ="green";
    document.getElementById("status1").innerHTML = "Status: løst";
  } else if (id === "button__solved2") {
    document.getElementById("weapon2").style.borderColor ="green";
    document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "Status: løst";
  } else if (id === "button__solved3") {
    document.getElementById("weapon3").style.borderColor ="green";
    document.getElementById("status3").innerHTML = "Status: løst";
  }
};

function notSolved(id){
  if (id === "button__not-solved1") {
    document.getElementById("weapon1").style.borderColor ="red";
    document.getElementById("status1").innerHTML = "Status: ikke løst";
  } else if (id === "button__not-solved2") {
    document.getElementById("weapon2").style.borderColor ="red";
    document.getElementById("status2").innerHTML = "Status: ikke løst";
  } else if (id === "button__not-solved3") {
    document.getElementById("weapon3").style.borderColor ="red";
    document.getElementById("status3").innerHTML = "Status: ikke løst";
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Is there anyway I can get the buttons only to react on the correpodning article. Say that I have 4 or 5 of these and I only want the buttons to alter the one that it is attached too

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  Are you saying you're going to have 4 or 5 different rectangular sections like the one you have now.  Each will have their own buttons and their own status?

Comment: Yes. I will try to update the snippet to illustrate

Comment: Okay.  There's a couple of ways to do this.  It'll help to see the snippet.

Comment: I have updatet it now. When i press any of the buttons it alters on the first rectangle and not the rectangle it is attached to

Comment: So one issue here is you're using the same ID for every instance of your Status list item.  IDs must be unique, so you can't use the same ID for every instance of Status.  You could create a new ID for each Status list item and a corresponding function for each, but that's not the most efficient route.  I have to go somewhere but can post some code to help out in an hour or so.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you so much

Comment: Okay take a look at my answer above.  I'm adding an edit now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add code as styles but create own classes. It's easier to follow the code if you do it like that.

The method `markArticle` has two parameters: the button itself and a string to be used as a class. The method goes up one step to the parent `article.weapon` element, and then removes eventual 'solved' and 'unsolved' classes only to add the correct one.

I used CSS to add text to `li.status`, through the pseudo-element `::after` but cheated a little bit with the spaces. I think it's actually clearer have two spans, inside `li.status`, with `<span class="solved">Löst</span>` and `<span class="unsolved">OLöst</span>` and then toggle the visibility of them based on what class `article.weapon` have. The pseudo-class code is just an example of how it can look like.

I also changed all `id="weapon"` to `"class="weapon"` for the articles and `id="status"` to `class="status"` for the li. You should only use `id` if it's a unique element, otherwise use classes. "Rex", "Snoopy" and "Lassie" are all unique ids but they all belong to the class "dogs".

```js
function markArticle(buttonElement, solvedClassStr){
  var articleElement = buttonElement.parentElement;

  if (articleElement) {
    articleElement.classList.remove('solved');
    articleElement.classList.remove('unsolved');

    articleElement.classList.add(solvedClassStr);
  }
};
```

```css
body{
        
        height: 100%;
        background-image:  url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490822061517-61b5e64bf21c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    h2{
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        color: white;
    }

    img{
        background: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .gallery{
    text-align: center;
      height: 400px;
      width: 600px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }

    #logo{
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        padding
    }

    .top-nav {
      background-color: black;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .topnavlinks {
      float: right;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;    
    }

    .top-nav a:hover {
      background-color: slategray;
      color: black;
    }

    .top-nav a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    #main-content-grid{
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 1rem;
    }

    #index-button{
        margin: 0.5rem;
        width: 25%;
        height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #555555;
        border: solid, 15px, black;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: white;
        outline: none;   
        display: inline;
    }

    .img-fluid{
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .Case-info{
        color: black;
        background: white;    
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size-adjust: auto;
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    }

    /*
        Mobile code        
    */

    .col-xs-12{
        grid-column: auto / span 12;
    }       

    /*
        Media queries
        *******
    */        

    /*
        Tablet
    */
    @media (min-width: 760px){

        .col-md-12{
            grid-column: auto / span 12;
        }

        .col-md-6{
            grid-column: auto / span 6;
        }            
    }

    /*        
        Smallest desktop >992px
    */        
    @media (min-width: 992px){
        .col-lg-12{
            grid-column: auto / span 12;
        }
        .col-lg-6{
            grid-column: auto / span 6;
        }
        .col-lg-4{
            grid-column: auto / span 4;
        }
    }


    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1rem;
        border: 2px, grey;
    }

    li{
        
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    /* ADDED */

    .weapon li.status {
      position: inline-block;
    }
    
    .weapon li.status::after {
       padding-left: 0.25rem;    
       display: inline-block;
    }

    .weapon.solved li.status::after {
       content: 'Löst';
    }

    .weapon.unsolved li.status::after {
       content: 'Olöst';
    }

    input{
        width: 50%;
        height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 12px;
        background-color: #555555;
        border: solid, 15px, black;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: white;
        outline: none;    
    }


    #spacing{
        height: 8rem;
    }

    .weapon{
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    /* ADDED */
    .weapon.solved {
       border: 1px solid green;
    }

    .weapon.unsolved {
       border: 1px solid red;
    }


    .top-nav{
        background: white;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Våpen smuglere</title>
        <script src="/Script/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Script/weapons.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/index.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/weaponsmugler.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>
       
       <div class="top-nav">
      <a href="Index.html">
          <img id=logo src="bilder/PST.png" alt="PST logo">
      </a>
      <a class="topnavlinks" href="login.html">Logg ut</a>
      <a  class="topnavlinks"href="Admin.html">Ny sak</a>
    </div>
       
       
       <div id="container">
        
        <div id="spacing">
            
        </div>
                
                        
           <main id="main-content-grid">
               
               <article class="weapon col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li class="status Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input class="solved" onclick="markArticle(this, 'unsolved')" type="button" value="Uløst">
                   <input class="solved" onclick="markArticle(this, 'solved')" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
 <article class="weapon col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li class="status Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input class="solved" onclick="markArticle(this, 'unsolved')" type="button" value="Uløst">
                   <input class="solved" onclick="markArticle(this, 'solved')" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
 <article class="weapon col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                   <h3>Mistenkt våpensmugling</h3>
                   <img class="img-fluid" src="bilder/VåpenSmugler.jpg">
                   <ul>
                       <li class="Case-info">Type sak: Våpensmugling</li>
                       <li class="status Case-info">Status:</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Mistenkte: Motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm</li>
                       <li class="Case-info">Beskrivelse: En motorsykkelklubb fra Lillestrøm er mistenkt i å smulge store mengeder våpen fra Russland via Finland</li>
                   </ul>
                    <input class="solved" onclick="markArticle(this, 'unsolved')" type="button" value="Uløst">
                   <input class="solved" onclick="markArticle(this, 'solved')" type="button" value="Løst">
               </article>
               
           </main>
           
       </div>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why your answer, nor mine, was down voted.

Comment: Can't do much without anyone explaining downvotes, so I can't really bother. :)

Comment: I read your answer and it's better than mine.  I'll upvote to get you some reputation back!  have a good one.

Comment: Haha. Cheers. ^^